# Firebase reports to be send to pre-configured users by email weekly or monthly

Tags: firebase, email, reporting, firebase-analytics

We used Firebase analytics in our Xamarin Forms app and we can check the analytics details via Firebase console dashboard.
We need to export these analytics report from dashboard and mail should trigger automatically to pre-configured users per weekly or monthly basis. Say, the report as an excel or document needs to be sent to multiple pre-configured users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per checking, there's no available feature in Firebase to send email notification to the users containing analytics reports. This is good to have, so I suggest you file a feature request on Firebase support [page](https://firebase.google.com/support).